# how to do memory manage of id<MTLTexture> to void* to IntPtr

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have working on an ios plugin to the unity. for sending an `id<MTLTexture>` on IOS to an `IntPtr` on unity.

**IOS:**

```
typedef struct
{
    void* texPtr;
}Ios_Struct;

id<MTLTexture> mtlTex;  // produced otherwhere, ARC

void foo_caller()
{
    ios_struct toBeSent;
    toBeSent.texPtr = (__bridge_retained void*)mtlTex;

    // call the callback that registered from Unity
    unityCallBack(toBeSent);

    // should I DO a release operation on the [toBeSent.texPtr]？
    // (__bridge_transfer id<MTLTexture>)toBeSent.texPtr;
}
```

**UNITY:**

```
public struct Unity_Struct;
{
    public IntPtr texPtr;
}

public delegate void Internal_Callback(Unity_Struct data);

// the callback that to be registered into IOS        
[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Internal_Callback))]
private static void toBeCalled(Unity_Struct sentData)
{
    IntPtr texPtr = sentData.texPtr;

    // to use the texPtr
}
```

I wonder that whether or not there is a memory leak from the `id<MTLTexture>` to `void*` to `intPtr`.

If any, is it right of releasing the `toBeSent.texPtr` by these steps:

```
// should I DO a release operation on the [toBeSent.texPtr]？
(__bridge_transfer id<MTLTexture>)toBeSent.texPtr;
```

Comment: did you find the answer? I have exactly the same problem.